# Integrate with which technique

Tags: calculus

$\int^{\ln6}_{\ln4}e^x\ln(e^{2x}-4)\,dx$  Hey, I have tried about everything, I used parts, , letting $dv=e^{2x}-4$ but it made the solution more complicated.  I believe the solution has something to do with a substitution of $e^{2x}-4$, but $u=e^{2x}-4$ doesn't seem to work because the derivative is $du=2e^{2x}$, which does not make the solution easier as well, I am a little stuck, any help would be appreciated

Comment: $e^{2x}-4=(e^x+2)(e^x-2)$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $dv=(e^{2x}-4)\,dx$.  But that can't work unless the function being integrated is $e^{2x}-4$ multiplied by something.  And it is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Setting $e^x=y$

$$\int_4^6\ln(y^2-4)\ dy$$

Now $\ln(y^2-4)=\ln(y-2)+\ln(y+2)$

Integrating by Parts,

$$\int \ln(y+a)\ dy=\ln(y+a)\int dy-\int\left[\dfrac{d\{\ln(y+a)\}}{dy}\cdot\int dy\right]\,dy$$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: I think you dropped an integral sign before the bracket?

Comment: @GPerez, Please find the edited version

Comment: So you intergrate both ln's seperately, then add them?

Comment: @Stack, Exactly

Comment: Oh, now it's there. Had you edited already though? In which case serious shame on mobile SE app.

Comment: For clarification, does the integral $ln(y + 2)dy=ln(y+2)y-\int\frac{y}{y-2}$